# Imported Excel sheet not sorted normally

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, excel

Below code to import data from excel sheet to ASP.Net web page and saving it at SQL server in my database.

When I import data from required sheet not imported by it's default sorting in ASP web page or database, and it is affect badly on the final result and lose data too.
For more clarification if first row in excel sheet having first ID is '1' , Activities is "New Installation" and so on...in the ASP web page and SQL Database may appear in ninth row and without full data

```
    using System;

    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Linq;

    using System.Web;

    using System.Web.UI;

    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    using System.IO;

    using System.Data;

    using System.Data.OleDb;

    namespace ImpExpExc
    {
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                PopulateData();
                lblMessage.Text = "Current Database Data!";
            }
        }




        private void PopulateData()
        {
            using (TEDataEntities dc = new TEDataEntities())
            {
                gvData.DataSource = dc.ImportExportExcels.ToList();
                gvData.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel" || 
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
            {
                try
                {
                    string fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ImportDocument"), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(fileName);

                    string conString = "";
                    string ext = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                    if (ext.ToLower() == ".xls")
                    {
                        conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                    }
                    else if (ext.ToLower() == ".xlsx")
                    {
                        conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                    }

                    string query = "Select [ID], [Activities], [Governorate], [Exchange], [Client], [Technician], [CircuitNo], [Comment], [Date] from [Sheet1$]";
                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
                    if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                    }
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    da.Dispose();
                    con.Close();
                    con.Dispose();

                    //Import to Database
                    using (TEDataEntities dc = new TEDataEntities())
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                        {
                            string empID = dr["ID"].ToString();
                            var v = dc.ImportExportExcels.Where(a => a.ID.Equals(empID)).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (v != null)
                            {
                                //Update here
                                v.Activities = dr["Activities"].ToString();
                                v.Governorate = dr["Governorate"].ToString();
                                v.Exchange = dr["Exchange"].ToString();
                                v.Client = dr["Client"].ToString();
                                v.Technician = dr["Technician"].ToString();
                                v.CircuitNo = dr["CircuitNo"].ToString();
                                v.Comment = dr["Comment"].ToString();
                                v.Date = dr["Date"].ToString();

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Insert here
                                dc.ImportExportExcels.AddObject(new ImportExportExcel
                                {
                                    ID = dr["ID"].ToString(),
                                    Activities = dr["Activities"].ToString(),
                                    Exchange = dr["Exchange"].ToString(),
                                    Client = dr["Client"].ToString(),
                                    Technician = dr["Technician"].ToString(),
                                    CircuitNo = dr["CircuitNo"].ToString(),
                                    Comment = dr["Comment"].ToString(),
                                    Date = dr["Date"].ToString()
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        dc.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    PopulateData();
                    lblMessage.Text = "Successfully data import done!";
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this issue happen because ID is string in code and nvarchar(50) in database but I don't know how to make it integer in code

Answer (score 0):

Finally issue of sorting solved by adding additional column with incremental ID in database but still some of cells which is related to date is empty